# How do I get current application locale?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, locale, nslocale

I need to get current locale. Not user locale but my application locale.

Let's say my application has two localizations (in project settings): English (default) and French. If user sets French language on iPhone then my application will display French interface. If user sets German language on iPhone then my application will display English interface (because English is default).

So how do I get current application locale that is showing right now?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The selected answer returns the current device language, but *not* the actual language used in the app. If you don't provide a localization for the preferred language in your app:

```
NSString *language = NSBundle.mainBundle.preferredLocalizations.firstObject;

NSLocale *locale = NSLocale.currentLocale;
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];

NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSString *country = [usLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode 
                                          value:countryCode];

NSLog(@"country: %@", country);
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way i can convert it to `NSLocale`?

Comment: Stealing other people's answer is not something we do on Stack Overflow, especially without credit. If an answer to another question can solve it then vote to close as duplicate. Don't steal the answer.

Answer (score 31):

*There may be an easier way than this (see other answers), but this one is most robust, and as long as the general principle of localizing an app through a `strings`-file doesn't get obsoleted, this method will work.*

Generally, you don't need to get the application locale (but read on, it's possible!) If you want localized text, you use `NSLocalizedString()`. If you need to localize images you use localized resources, and so on. However, there are reasons that I can think of which would make it nice to get the "application locale", as you call it: for example for analytics (you want to know in which language your app is used), or for providing a consistent one-language interface to the user if you use server-based communication (e.g. to localize the server error messages in the same language that the user is seeing inside the app.)

If you want to get the localization of the app that is currently visible, I suppose you have a `Localizable.strings` file for each supported locale. So, in the Englisch strings-file you can add the line

```
"lang" = "en";
```

and in the French string-file you add the line

```
"lang" = "fr";
```

then, you can always get the application-locale by calling `NSLocalizedString("lang")` (swift) or `NSLocalizedString(@"lang")` (objective-C). And of course, whenever you add a new localization to your app, you have to set a "lang" entry into the new localizations strings-file.

Answer (score 14):

In Swift 3 use:

`let language = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first`

Answer (score 4):

You can get country code from locale, this way,

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];  // get the current locale.
NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

Get country code, e.g. `es` (Spain), `fr` (France), etc.

You can map this code for your interface selection.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can get selected language using following code.

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

if ([language isEqualToString:@"fr"]){//French
    [do  your stuff]
}
else{//English

   [do  your stuff]
}
```

[List_of_ISO_639-1_codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: As mentioned, this gives you he iPhone System language. [[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations].firstObject gives the "best match" of the apps languages with the users prioritised languages list.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is way simpler than the ones proposed:

Device language

`let deviceLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages.first`

Actual app translation

`let language = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first`

For instance, I set my iPhone in English-Indian and my app doesn't have English-Indian translation but only English-UK:

```
Printing description of language:
"en-GB"
Printing description of deviceLanguage:
"en-IN"
```

Comment: For some reason `Locale.preferredLanguages[0]` gives me just `en`. I don't get the country code.