# How in iOS to localize text of the month in UIDatePicker, and if it is possible at all?

Tags: ios, localization, uidatepicker

I make search and up to now I see that UIDatePicker is working with localization of the device.

I have app which has internal lozalization. I need to change month's text dependantly of my internal localization. As I read it appears that this is not possible - I have to make my own custom picker.

Is there a way to achieve that without custom Dat picker?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use locale property of UIDatePicker. I can't see any signs that the property is deprecated.

This code will localize picker to Japanese.

```
[datePicker setLocale: [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja"]];
```

Replace "ja" with any language code you need.

Comment: 10x, @Andrey Kuznetsov works great! I also think to use that, but when I search over the web I see many different solutions, so I get confused.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35499631/3340702) for the **swift** version.

Comment: But Time displaying 12 Hrs format instead of 24 Hrs.

Comment: 12/24 hour format depends on locale setup and could be changed from default by user in system settings. So there is no 100% reliable way to do this. See question https://stackoverflow.com/q/11151187/ for more information on that

Answer (score 12):

**With Swift**

```
let datePicker:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "it_IT")
```

Replace the `it_IT` string (for *Italian-speaking* people) with your locale identifier. Common cases for english are:

- `en` for generic *English-speaking* people
- `en_US` for *English-speaking* residents of the United States
- `en_GB` for *English-language* speakers in the United Kingdom

For more information about the locale identifier see the [*Locale IDs* section of "Internationalization and Localization Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH15-SW9) by Apple

If you're interested in getting the current locale see [How do I get current application locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986991/how-do-i-get-current-application-locale)

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.0 and New**

This code will locale picker to Chinese.
Here datePicker is object of UIDatePicker.

```
datePicker.locale = Locale.init(localeIdentifier: "zh-Hans")
```

- Use `"en"` instead of `"zh-Hans"` for English .
- Use `"az-Arab"` instead of `"zh-Hans"` for Arabic.
- Use `"uz-Latn"` instead of `"zh-Hans"` for Latin.

for more : [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH15-SW9)

Answer (score 1):

The UIDatePicker, by default, uses whatever [NSLocale currentLocale] dictates.

The locale property on UIDatePicker was deprecated in iOS 5, but you can try this:

```
NSLocale *loc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"..."];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[cal setLocale:loc];
[myDatePicker setCalendar:cal];
```

Comment: I try this @arturdev. It does not working. My `UIDatePickerView` is in `Storyboard`. When I put this for a specific language - it not affects App when it runs - the default is English. I can set `Locale` in designer - it is ok, but I don't know how to change it during runtime. When I change language in the App I need also localize.

Answer (score 0):

UIDatePicker localize is dependent  on the "Region Format" setting of device.

Settings > General > International > Region Format

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with selecting UIDatepicker control may be you can do it with UIPickerview. please check this link. (you can do it like this way)
[UI appearance Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844675/custom-ios-uidatepicker-using-uiappearance) 
           or 
[Custom Color of Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181225/customize-text-color-of-uidatepicker-for-ios7-just-like-mailbox-does)
I hope it is helpfull to you.