# How to have this date picker mode?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

[image: The image]

The reminders app uses this date picker mode of "wed, april 20" and the hours, but in my app, I'd like to have only the "wed, april 20" format. I'm using the normal Date mode (date - month - year) right now, but as it is not showing the date's name its a bit confusing. Is this a normal mode that I can use (the reminders app mode)?

Taking the flow of the question, I also wanna ask something: to set the date picker as a text field's input view I need to create an action of the text field and use `textField.inputView = datePicker`
Right?

Reply to the questions you know, or both, thanks in advance!

Comment: you tried looking here ? http://blog.deeplink.me/post/81386967477/how-to-easily-customize-uidatepicker-for-ios

Comment: datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
ans [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569602/how-in-ios-to-localize-text-of-the-month-in-uidatepicker-and-if-it-is-possible

Answer (score 0):

The date format of the `UIDatePicker` can only be set using it's `mode` property and it doesn't allow a lot of flexibility, like displaying a week day. If you want to achieve this you either have to make your own date picker using a `UIPickerView`, or find some of the third-party components available online.

Answer (score 0):

You can change datePicker mode as

```
[picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
```